# To convert the json date which is coming from solr to actual date (yyyy/mm/dd)

Tags: json

```
Var idate =res.results[r].date
```

date  is coming from solr

The above line output is in the format

```
Mon Apr 22 14:49:00 2019
```

I have tried code but I am getting today's date I want the date which is coming from solr below is the code

```
Var idate2=new Date(idate)//idate I am passing which is coming from solr.....
Var n=idate2.Tolocaledatestring();
Console.log(n);
```

Output I am getting is `5/5/2019` but I want `22/5/2019`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for convert your date:

```
var date = new Date('Mon Apr 22 14:49:00 2019');

var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();

var result = day + '/' + month + '/' + year; // output is 22/3/2019
```